# How can I print over the current line in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I want to have a simple counter on a line that changes. I have the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
for i in range(400):
    print("\r" + str(i), end = "")
    sleep(0.5)
```

In Python 3, it works fine, with the counter incrementing on the same line, but in Python 2, nothing displays. How can I get it to display in Python 2?

---

EDIT: I am inclined towards solutions that work for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: works for me just ensure that the (output is unbuffered)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep
for i in range(400):
    print"\r"+str(i),
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
```